# Least common multiple on serie of number

Tags: least-common-multiple

My problem is the following, for an application i need the lowest number which can be divided bij the following set of numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15.

My first sollution was 15! - 7! since all number which are undernearth 8 (so 7 and lower) can allways be divided by when dividing by a higher number. I know i can also divide this outcome by 10 and make it still dividable, but i think there shouldeven be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in general. Let $p$ denote a prime.

$$LCM(1,...,N) = \prod_{p\le N} p^{\lfloor\log_{p}(N)\rfloor} $$

For $N=15$ we have

$$LCM(1,...,15) = \prod_{p\le 15} p^{\lfloor\log_{p}(15)\rfloor} = (2^3)(3^2)(5)(7)(11)(13)$$

Answer (score 2):

For each prime, you just need to find the maximum number of factors that are in one number. For $2$, that is $3$, coming from $8$, for $3$ you need $2$ because of $9$.  All other primes come once each.  If you need it for other top values, they are given in [OEIS A003418](http://oeis.org/A003418)